# Storing user input values into an array and displaying them shows garbage values

Tags: c, arrays, loops, storage

I am working on a simple program that asks the user to input an even number and input an odd number. They are stored in the arrays `storeItem1` and `storeItem2` respectively. The program asks the user twice. The problem is with my output. I want to **display the values the user input**.

My exit condition for the for loop I'll use to display the values is `if(!storeItem1)break;` which ends the loop once the current element of the array is null. However the output ends up like this.

```
Even Numbers Are: 2
Even Numbers Are: 4
Even Numbers Are: some garbage value
Odd Numbers Are: 1
Odd Numbers Are: 3
Odd Numbers Are: some garbage value
```

What I don't understand is why isn't the condition terminating the loop once the iteration of the loop reaches the part where the array element is null? Shouldn't it end after displaying all array values that aren't null? Here is my code attached below. Thanks in advance!

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(void)
{
    int storeItem1[8], storeItem2[8], even, odd;
    int i=0, j=0, dis=0, dis2=0;

    do
    {
        printf("Input Even Number: ");
        scanf("%d",&even);
        storeItem1[j]=even;

        printf("Input Odd Number: ");
        scanf("%d",&odd);
        storeItem2[j]=odd;

        ++j;
        ++i;

    }while(i<2); //asks user to input twice

    //display the stored values
    for(dis;dis<8;++dis) //display all input even numbers
    {
        if(!storeItem1[dis])break; //exits loop when current array element is null
        printf("\nEven Numbers are: %d",storeItem1[dis]);

    }

    for(dis2;dis2<8;++dis2) //display all input odd numbers
    {
        if(!storeItem2[dis2])break; //exits loop when current array element is null
        printf("\nOdd Numbers are: %d",storeItem2[dis2]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your arrays `storeItem1` and `storeItem2` contain garbage unless you explicitly initialize them.

Comment: @NateEldredge wouldn't my ```if(!storeItem1)break;``` condition recognize that the other values in the array contain garbage values?

Comment: No, your test `if(!storeItem1[dis])` only tests whether `storeItem1[dis]` is zero or not.  It's exactly the same as writing `if(storeItem1[dis] == 0)`.  The garbage value can certainly be nonzero.  It might be 57, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @NateEldredge, I really have to study arrays from a more nuanced resource.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite embarrassed to answer my question so quickly. I modified my loop conditions such that,

```
for(dis;dis<i;++dis)
    {
        //if(!storeItem1[dis])break; //exits loop when current array element is null
        printf("\nEven Numbers are: %d",storeItem1[dis]);

    }

    for(dis2;dis2<j;++dis2)
    {
        //if(!storeItem2[dis2])break; //exits loop when current array element is null
        printf("\nOdd Numbers are: %d",storeItem2[dis2]);
    }
```

the loop automatically terminates itself without the requirement of a conditional statement to exit. The condition in the for initialization has been modified such that the variable `dis<i and dis2<j` and will terminate once they reach the same value as `i and j`.

Thank you all.